# Create a bootable usb drive with simple message

Tags: boot, usb-flash-drive

This should be simple but cannot get my head around it.
Want to create a bootable usb drive (FreeDos, Syslinux GrubforDos) really don't care. 
All I need is it to boot and display a simple message and enter to quit and reboot.

Ideas?

Comment: yes any one of the virus generation tools will do this just fine

Answer (score 3):

I'd personally use Syslinux / ISOLinux with a non existent default menu item with pressing Ctrl Alt Del to reboot the box. The title on the non existent item could be your message.

As long as you don't specify a timeout in the menu config it should do about what you want.

Comment: Or instead of a menu, maybe use the Fancy graphics support to display an image of your choosing, that has whatever you want displayed.

Comment: I do like the idea of a fancy graphics display.. Ideas?

Comment: The process is about the same from what I have read. I don't use boot splash screens however so I can't be of much more help.